# CiviCRM/Wordpress Newsletters and eStores

Tags: newsletter, woocommerce

I'm vetting a CiviCRM/Wordpress solution for a small non-profit org I'm volunteering for.  I'm looking for confirmation of the limitations of the platform to better communicate what items on the wish-list are impossible or very challenging to deliver.

While Civi seems to handle membership, donations, events and volunteer signups fairly easily, it seems e-newsletters and e-shop (i.e. - Woocommerce) are not particularly functional out of the box, correct?

For example, while we can send bulk emails generally, there's no capacity for automatically create web archives/blog post/public url for e-newsletters. Nor can the latest WP blog be added into a content block in an email template automagically.

And Civi has no e-store nor integration with WooCommerce, so New customers do not trigger new contacts in CiviCRM.  Likewise, completed orders for exiting contacts is not reflected in Civi.

These aren't dealbreakers of course, just trying to better understand the limitations...I don't think any of the CRM's actually merge all of these different functions.

Comment: Hi. For WooCommerce it might be worth looking at https://github.com/WPCV/wpcv-woo-civi-integration as that may meet your requirements. And hopefully someone can provide some potential solutions for the mailing questions.

Comment: Civi does provide for CiviMailings to have a public link/url but i take it that would be the least of your concerns at this point